# How to solve Connection Error VB.net & SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an application which runs perfectly, but sometimes I get the following error. I have attached the screen shot below. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Local or remote server?

Comment: Database is on different machine & front end is on different machine

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text.  Post the text.  Also, post the code that causes the error.  That said, if you can connect sometimes and not others then the issue is not the code but rather that the database is accessible sometimes and not others.  That may be due to the network connection or something else unrelated to your code that we can't help with.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens, when your application cannot connect to a server due to, for example incorrect connection string, which is not the case, since you said it works most of the time. To make sure everything is OK, validate your onnection string.

Second thing that comes to my mind is that, it your application just cannot connect with remote server, that database is running on. Try pinging your IP or DNS name in command line using `ping` and see what the result is.